# DB Error on contribution form unless signed in

Tags: drupal, civicontribute

On one of our contribution forms for users to sign up and pay for a membership, we are getting a DB Error. Here is a screenshot of the contribution form so you can see where they are urged to create an account.
[image]

Here is the error log message, where `test@example.com` is my test user, who submitted a transaction and created an account on the form. I used a fresh email address, just replaced it here:

```
[info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -5
    [message] => DB Error: already exists
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_match (domain_id , uf_id , uf_name , contact_id ) VALUES ( 1 ,  209115 , 'test@example.com' ,  140637 )  [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'test@example.com-1' for key 'UI_uf_name_domain_id']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_match (domain_id , uf_id , uf_name , contact_id ) VALUES ( 1 ,  209115 , 'test@example.com' ,  140637 )  [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'test@example.com-1' for key 'UI_uf_name_domain_id']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: already exists" code=-5 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_uf_match (domain_id , uf_id , uf_name , contact_id ) VALUES ( 1 ,  209115 , 'test@example.com' ,  140637 )  [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'test@example.com-1' for key 'UI_uf_name_domain_id']"]
)
```

The transaction came into the CRM as Pending (Incomplete Transaction). I also processed a test donation, a contribution form that doesn't require the user to create an account, and I did not get an error, however, the transaction still came in as Pending (Incomplete Transaction).

I have recently upgraded to CiviCRM 5.9.0 and Drupal 7.63.

Comment: may be worth seeing if you can duplicate on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like drupal username "test@example.com" already exists, when contribution form is submitted, it is trying to add a new drupal user and civicrm contact which is failing because of a duplicate.

Comment: I know but it didn't. It does it every time. Meaning it's creating it and then creating it again in the same transaction. Also, I don't believe it's Drupal, it's ufc domain match.

Comment: Do you have any drupal rule setup or any other customization which would be creating drupal user other than civi default behavior?